# ¿Cómo enlazo una lista a el índice del renglón de otra?

Tags: c#, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Soy novato, recién estoy aprendiendo C#. Lo que requiero es poder enlazar una lista a otra; de manera que cuando doy clic en cualquier celda de una Lista en una DataGridView; la segunda DataGridView me muestre exclusivamente datos de sólo cuando doy clic en ese renglón (pertenezcan a ese índice aún si los ordeno). Sinceramente no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo. Para esto, me pidieron usar una lista que contiene a otra como uno de sus atributos.

Solo he logrado que la segunda DataGridView me muestre datos cuando doy clic en el renglón. Pero son los datos de toda la lista; no logro relacionarlos sólo con un renglón en específico.
(Ejemplo)
Cuando doy clic en un nombre se despliega la dtg de abajo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo al ingresar los datos a un segundo renglón; no logro saber cómo relacionarlo con datos exclusivos a dicho renglón y se suman.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código importante es el siguiente (separado por capas)

```
public class ManejadorUsuario
{
    //Tablas de manejo
    public static List<EntidadUsuario> usuario = new List<EntidadUsuario>();
    public static List<EntidadContacto> contacto  = new List<EntidadContacto>();
public void AddUsuario(string ucodigo, string unombre, List<EntidadContacto>lcontacto)
    {

        lcontacto = contacto;
        usuario.Add(new EntidadUsuario(ucodigo, unombre, lcontacto));
        
    }
}

public partial class frmAgregarContactos : Form
{
   
    public frmAgregarContactos()
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Actualizar()
    {
        dtgContactos.DataSource = ManejadorUsuario.contacto.ToList();
        dtgContactos.AutoResizeColumns();
        txtNumero.Clear(); txtNombreContact.Clear(); txtTelefono.Clear(); txtNumero.Focus();

    }

    private void btnAgregarContactos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmUsuario.mu.AddContacto(txtNumero.Text, txtNombreContact.Text, txtTelefono.Text);
        Actualizar();
        
    }
}

public partial class frmUsuario : Form
{
   public static ManejadorUsuario mu;
    public frmUsuario()
    {
        mu = new ManejadorUsuario();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void ActualizarUser()
    {
        dtgUsuario.DataSource = ManejadorUsuario.usuario.ToList();
        dtgUsuario.AutoResizeColumns();
    }
    public void ActualizarContact()
    {
        dtgshowcontact.DataSource = ManejadorUsuario.contacto.ToList();
        dtgUsuario.AutoResizeColumns();
    }

    private void btnAgregarContactos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmAgregarContactos au = new frmAgregarContactos();
        au.ShowDialog();

        mu.AddUsuario(txtCodigo.Text, txtNombre.Text, ManejadorUsuario.contacto);
        ActualizarUser();

    }

    private void dtgUsuario_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       // int index = dtgUsuario.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        ActualizarContact();

    }
}
```

Como ven, no están enlazados, y es que no se me ocurrió la manera de hacerlos.

Comment: te estaria faltando primero que nada colocar un campo donde puedas enlazar los datos de una tabla con otra, porque no veo que haya nada que los una. A los contactos deberias agregarlo el UCodigo, luego cuando tocas la fila extraes ese Ucodigo y lo buscas en el listado de contactos y luego asignas el resultado al listview

Comment: Así es, muchas gracias. Con uCodigo pude enlazarlos y que solo se muestre la lista de contactos cuando el uCodigo coincida en ambas listas